# .NET 6 - reading Xml with schema as string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, .net-6.0

I'm trying to load an xml file which schema comes as a string:

```
using (MemoryStream memStream = GenerateStreamFromString(XsdSchemas.the_schema_string))
{
   // tried this one too => using TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(memStream);
   using XmlTextReader xmlReader = new(memStream);
   settings.Schemas.Add(THE_NAMESPACE_S, xmlReader);
}

private static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
      throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
   MemoryStream memStream = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
   memStream.Position = 0; // just in case
   return memStream;
}
```

But I can't get it to work. The debug shows `xmlReader` as **"None"**. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Remove the using before XmlTextReader it is masking an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making this far too complicated.

Use `new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(theString))`.

The MemoryStream is completely unnecessary. Having said that, I don't know why it's failing.

Comment: The intent was to use XSD schema and expect XmlReader to fail if the XML doc is not valid. But turns out one has to use `ValidationEventHandler` to be able to do this! Yikes! But thanks anyway!